# System Rollback all Files Deleted

Tags: backup

After some issues with Upgrade to latest stable versions of components I decided to rollback, so I went to System > Tools > Backups and clicked on Rollback of latest System Backup I did before the upgrade. I also did a Database and Media Backup.

Now I get the following error and it seems that a  large number of files have disappeared on the server side:

Warning: include_once(Mage/Core/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/web108/html/www/app/Mage.php on line 50 Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Mage/Core/functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/web108/html/www/app/code/local:/var/www/web108/html/www/app/code/community:/var/www/web108/html/www/app/code/core:/var/www/web108/html/www/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/php/PEAR:/var/www/web108/html') in /var/www/web108/html/www/app/Mage.php on line 50 Warning: include_once(Varien/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/web108/html/www/app/Mage.php on line 51 Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Varien/Autoload.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/web108/html/www/app/code/local:/var/www/web108/html/www/app/code/community:/var/www/web108/html/www/app/code/core:/var/www/web108/html/www/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/php/PEAR:/var/www/web108/html') in /var/www/web108/html/www/app/Mage.php on line 51 Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Autoload' not found in /var/www/web108/html/www/app/Mage.php on line 54

This is a terrible situation, completely lost here for next steps, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have compilation mode enabled. Try disabling it and reloading, the error should go away after that.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I cannot access Admin Panel anymore, how do I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538154/magento-died-after-compilation-how-to-disable-using-compiled-files-without-admi

Comment: Thanks folder includes is no longer there. looked at the backup I have and the config.php file shows those two lines commented out.

Comment: Try "php shell/compiler.php disable" anyway from your root Magento folder via SSH.

Comment: I was not able to access server by SSH, requested a server restore instead. This has now been done but I continue to have problems, I created a new request here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37556/printing-exception-after-files-and-db-restore

Comment: If this is fixed please mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

i used this command and did it. 
php -f compiler.php clear
php -f compiler.php disable